# Unable to use axios in js function

Tags: vue.js, axios

We are building an application using VueJS, are new to its concepts. Facing an error when we try to make a call using axios from a js function. 
The error is "export 'default' (imported as axios) was not found in ./axios.js"

Please let us know what we might be doing wrong. Appreciate your help.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import axios from './axios.js';

export const MY_CONST = 'Vue.js';
export let memberList = new Vue({
    el: '#members',
    data: {
        members: []
    },

    mounted: function () {
        this.getAllMembers();
    },

    methods: {
        getAllMembers: function () {
            var me = this;
            axios.get("https://xxxxx.com/services/api.php")
                .then(function (response) {
                    me.members = response.data.members;
                });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: what is exporting in your axios.js file

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've installed `axios` as a dependency or devDependency in your package.json and installed it via `npm` or `yarn` then I would suspect your issue is that you're looking for axios in a file called `axios.js` in the same directory as the calling component.  You should instead look for the package `axios` like this:

`import axios from 'axios';`

If you're indeed trying to export `axios` from a custom file with configuration or something then you need to see what you're exporting from the file and make sure it is indeed `axios`. Though from the sound of your error that doesn't seem to be what your'e trying to do.

Comment: You are right, we were trying to import from just 'axios.js'. Will try to install using npm as a package. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Your suggestion worked, it had to be installed as a package. Thank you very much.

Comment: @KrishnanVS if this indeed did work for you could you accept this as the answer?

Comment: I tried to but it said I need certain credits. Thanks for your help, appreciate it.